# Problem with sending message from flume to kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, centos7, cloudera, flume

I have two hosts in two different VMs,
i have flume on a Centos 7 host and kafka on cloudera host.
So i connected the two of them and make kafka in the cloudera host as sink in flume as represent the code bellow :

```
# Name the components on this agent
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = spooldir
a1.sources.r1.spoolDir = /root/Bureau/V1/outputCV
a1.sources.r1.fileHeader = true
a1.sources.r1.interceptors = timestampInterceptor
a1.sources.r1.interceptors.timestampInterceptor.type = timestamp

# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.topic = flume-topic
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.bootstrap.servers = 
192.168.5.129:9090,192.168.5.129:9091,192.168.5.129:9092
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.flumeBatchSize = 20
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.producer.acks = 1
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.producer.linger.ms = 1
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.producer.compression.type = snappy

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

I got this error when flume try to send messages to kafka :

```
[root@localhost V1]# /root/flume/bin/flume-ng agent --name a1 --conf-file /root/Bureau/V1/flumeconf/flumetest.conf
Warning: No configuration directory set! Use --conf <dir> to override.
Warning: JAVA_HOME is not set!
Info: Including Hadoop libraries found via (/root/hadoop/bin/hadoop) for HDFS access
Info: Including Hive libraries found via () for Hive access
+ exec /usr/bin/java -Xmx20m -cp '/root/flume/lib/*:/root/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/root/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/root/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/root/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/root/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/root/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/root/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/root/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/root/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn:/root/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/root/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/lib/*' -Djava.library.path=:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib org.apache.flume.node.Application --name a1 --conf-file /root/Bureau/V1/flumeconf/flumetest.conf
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/flume/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2019-05-07 19:04:41,363 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Configuration provider starting
2019-05-07 19:04:41,366 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Reloading configuration file:/root/Bureau/V1/flumeconf/flumetest.conf
2019-05-07 19:04:41,374 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:c1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:r1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:r1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Added sinks: k1 Agent: a1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:r1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:r1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:r1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:c1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:r1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:c1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,375 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Agent configuration for 'a1' has no configfilters.
2019-05-07 19:04:41,392 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [a1]
2019-05-07 19:04:41,392 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Creating channels
2019-05-07 19:04:41,397 INFO channel.DefaultChannelFactory: Creating instance of channel c1 type memory
2019-05-07 19:04:41,400 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Created channel c1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,401 INFO source.DefaultSourceFactory: Creating instance of source r1, type spooldir
2019-05-07 19:04:41,415 INFO sink.DefaultSinkFactory: Creating instance of sink: k1, type: org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
2019-05-07 19:04:41,420 INFO kafka.KafkaSink: Using the static topic flume-topic. This may be overridden by event headers
2019-05-07 19:04:41,426 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Channel c1 connected to [r1, k1]
2019-05-07 19:04:41,432 INFO node.Application: Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{r1=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:Spool Directory source r1: { spoolDir: /root/Bureau/V1/outputCV } }} sinkRunners:{k1=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@492cf580 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{c1=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: c1}} }
2019-05-07 19:04:41,432 INFO node.Application: Starting Channel c1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,492 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: c1: Successfully registered new MBean.
2019-05-07 19:04:41,492 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: CHANNEL, name: c1 started
2019-05-07 19:04:41,492 INFO node.Application: Starting Sink k1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,494 INFO node.Application: Starting Source r1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,494 INFO source.SpoolDirectorySource: SpoolDirectorySource source starting with directory: /root/Bureau/V1/outputCV
2019-05-07 19:04:41,525 INFO producer.ProducerConfig: ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [192.168.5.129:9090, 192.168.5.129:9091, 192.168.5.129:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = 
    compression.type = snappy
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 1
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer

2019-05-07 19:04:41,536 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: SOURCE, name: r1: Successfully registered new MBean.
2019-05-07 19:04:41,536 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SOURCE, name: r1 started
2019-05-07 19:04:41,591 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 2.0.1
2019-05-07 19:04:41,591 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : fa14705e51bd2ce5
2019-05-07 19:04:41,592 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: SINK, name: k1: Successfully registered new MBean.
2019-05-07 19:04:41,592 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SINK, name: k1 started
2019-05-07 19:05:01,780 INFO avro.ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader: Last read took us just up to a file boundary. Rolling to the next file, if there is one.
2019-05-07 19:05:01,781 INFO avro.ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader: Preparing to move file /root/Bureau/V1/outputCV/cv.txt to /root/Bureau/V1/outputCV/cv.txt.COMPLETED
2019-05-07 19:05:03,673 WARN clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -2 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-05-07 19:05:03,776 WARN clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -2 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-05-07 19:05:03,856 WARN clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -2 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-05-07 19:05:03,910 INFO clients.Metadata: Cluster ID: F_Byx5toQju8jaLb3zFwAA
2019-05-07 19:05:04,084 WARN clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error connecting to node quickstart.cloudera:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: quickstart.cloudera:9092
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doConnect(Selector.java:235)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:214)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:864)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.sendProducerData(Sender.java:266)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:238)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doConnect(Selector.java:233)
    ... 7 more
2019-05-07 19:05:04,140 WARN clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error connecting to node quickstart.cloudera:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: quickstart.cloudera:9092
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doConnect(Selector.java:235)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:214)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:864)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.sendProducerData(Sender.java:266)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:238)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doConnect(Selector.java:233)
    ... 7 more
2019-05-07 19:05:04,231 WARN clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error connecting to node quickstart.cloudera:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: quickstart.cloudera:9092
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doConnect(Selector.java:235)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:214)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:864)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.sendProducerData(Sender.java:266)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:238)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doConnect(Selector.java:233)
    ... 7 more
2019-05-07 19:05:04,393 WARN clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error connecting to node quickstart.cloudera:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
```

Error connectiong to node shows up only after sending messages.

Can anyone helps me solve this problem.

Comment: please do not share images/links, copy and paste the errors instead.

Comment: Ok, i just did it.

Comment: put that address on /etc/hosts so it can be resolved

Comment: i already did this in both hosts but still the same issue

Comment: it says WARN clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -2 could not be established. Broker may not be available.

Comment: check if advertised listeners holds the same name

Comment: i don't get it sorry what exactly is advertised listeners and where to find them